# Allow Editor Role to Edit Media

Tags: media, media-library, permissions

On a multisite, I have an Editor role that is assigned to subsite1. When that user logs in to their assigned sub-site (that user is an 'editor' on that subsite) and goes to the Media page, they see the media for their site.

But that user cannot click on a picture (media item) and get to the Edit screen (as when they need to rotate an image, for example). That capability appears to be a function that only works for the Admin and SuperAdmin role.

I've looked that the Roles and Capabilities page in the Codex (here https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities ), and don't see how to add that Media Edit capability - I don't see a 'Media Edit' capability.

How can I let the 'Editor' role Edit Media?

**Edited** to clarify that the user (with the Editor role) is logging into their subsite, and can see the Media page, but cannot click on a media item (picture) to get to that picture-edit page.

Comment: Taking a look at `\wp-admin\includes\media.php`, the users with the `edit_post` capability can edit media files since the medias are posts actually (attachment post type). But you have assigned your editor to another site, so that might be why they can't edit the media files.

Comment: That's what I determined from my research. But the logged in 'editor' user is logged into his subsite, but cannot click on a picture to edit it. Nothing happens. (That editor has not been assigned to another site. Have edited the question to make that clear.)

Comment: as jack says it should just work. probably worth turning off plugins and switching theme